# JQuery add div to Facebook posts fails because of dynamic loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, greasemonkey, mouseover

I'm using the mouseover function to add extra content to a Facebook group. I test the DIV class to see if I have already added content.

It works for the first 10 or so DIVs with class storyInnerWrapper but then stops adding the text.  I think it is due to the content being dynamic like  Arun P Johny said below.

Here is a JSfiddle working example;
http://jsfiddle.net/hellonearthis/WHb2P/ with the fix and it works fine with the example.

Full grease monkey script below.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       FaceBook
// @version    0.1
// @description  Adds link 
// @match      https://www.facebook.com/*
// @match      https://www.facebook.com/
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==

$( "div.storyInnerWrapper" ).mouseover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data('extra')) { 
        $this.data('extra', true);
        $this.append('<div>Added a div</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or some sample markup for this? Also, are you adding the id "extra" to multiple elements? If so, you want to avoid that, as ID should be unique per page to only one element. Doesn't answer your question yet but an observation nonetheless.

Comment: whether the `storyInnerWrapper` elements are dynamically added

Comment: This code has too much complexity. Try simplifying. For example saving an index only "un-index" three times in a row is confusing. Also it isn't clear what the if statment is looking for. I think you are better off re-examining the problem. The responsibility of the mouseover event is to far reaching to make a clear understanding of the solution. You could also consider using unique ID's based on content so you can check if the div was added easier.

Comment: Also the id of an element must be unique so you cannot assign the id `extra` to more than  1 element

Comment: A simplified version of the current code can be `$("div.storyInnerWrapper").mouseover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('extra')) {
        $this.addClass('extra'); // tag add 
        $this.append("<div>Added a div</div>");
    }
});`

Comment: Also, since you mentioned you are new to javascript and jquery, not sure if you are familiar with http://jsfiddle.net but you can post examples for us to help with there.

Comment: Added the jsFiddle and expanded the issue with facebook greasemonkey script.  Yes Arun the elements are being added dynamically I think,  I though the mouseover adding would handle the page dynamic updates as it's still hitting the elements of the same class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the "id" attribute to "tag" an element. The "id" values must be unique. Instead, you could use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to mark the element, like this:

```
$('div.storyInnerWrapper').mouseover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data('extra')) { 
        $this.data('extra', true);
        $this.append('<div>Added a div</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I though I was doing it wrong by using ID's and the use of the var is much more elegant style.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the Dynamic content problem I was having I used [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891)
Mentioned countless times by [Brock Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams)  Also big thanks to [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) for pointing me in the right direction and to [John S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859640/john-s) for helping me improve the base code.

The final Greasemonkey scripts looks like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       FaceBook_add_stuff
// @description  Adds a div to wall posts when mouse is over them.
// @match      https://www.facebook.com/*
// @match      https://www.facebook.com/
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

function addExtraSeedLinks (jNode) {
    $( "div.storyInnerWrapper" ).mouseover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.data('extra')) { 
            $this.data('extra', true);
            $this.append('<div>Added a div</div>');
        }
    });
}

waitForKeyElements (".storyInnerWrapper", addExtraSeedLinks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
$( "div.storyInnerWrapper" ).mouseover(function() {
    //var index = $( "div.storyInnerWrapper" ).index();

    if ($("div.extra.storyInnerWrapper").index()== 0){  // if no tag

        $("div.storyInnerWrapper" ).append( "<div class='extra'>Added a div</div>" );
  }
});
```

Note that I've replaced #extra with .extra as id should be unique.